# Why do references to anonymous functions continue to live?

Tags: javascript

Samurai relies on ninja.chirp but I removed the reference to ninja.chirp. Why does this code continue to work?

```
    var ninja = {
        chirp: function (n) {
            return n > 1 ? this.chirp(n - 1) + '-chirp' : 'chirp'; 
        }
    };

    function chirp(n) {
        return n > 1 ? chirp(n-1) + '-chirp' : 'chirp'; 
    }

    var samurai = {
        chirp: ninja.chirp
    };

    ninja = {};
    try {
        console.log(samurai.chirp(3));
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("no can do.");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see anonymous functions

Comment: @runners: All functions are objects, and all objects are held via reference. So there can be many different references held to the same object. Destroying one reference doesn't destroy the others. When all references are destroyed, the object becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: i see... is that the same behavior in C++? like if i create an object in c++, and call that reference later  on another function but i destroy that obj,  the callback would not work.

Comment: I don't know C++ well enough to answer, but I do know that it's a much more complex language with many more options for handling data. Memory can be used directly, via pointers, via references, and I'm probably just scratching the surface.

Comment: C++ is not garbage collected.  Javascript is.  In C++ you explicitly destroy objects, in Javascript you "abandon" them.  In JS if someone else is holding a reference, they are not "destroyed"(garbage collected) until that reference is released, as Blue Skies said.

Comment: @runners3413 It is the same behavior, with the difference being that in JS you cannot destroy objects. Objects are only destroyed by the garbage collector which runs after the object is no longer accessible (no more references to it, or inaccessible references only).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have

```
var a = {};
```

You actually have two things:

- an object with no properties that exists in memory
- a reference towards that object stored in variable `a`

When you do:

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
```

You actually have three things:

- an object with no properties that exists in memory
- a reference towards that object stored in variable `a`
- another reference towards that object stored in variable `b`

That is why when you later do `a = null;`, b still holds a reference to the original object.

The same thing happens in your case, even though it is slightly more obscured by objects, properties and functions.